# The Z transform: why $z^{-n}$ and not $z^n$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, signal-processing

The Z-transform for a discrete signal is defined as $X(z) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} x[n]z^{-n}$. I was wondering why we invert the exponent of $z$, rather than define it as $X(z) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} x[n]z^{n}$, which to my mind seems like a more natural definition.

I've not been able to find an answer for this anywhere. Both definitions seem to give pretty much the same theory (but different domains of convergence in applications).

Comment: If you try factoring the denominator of $$\dfrac{1}{R^2-5R+6}$$

and decompose it as partial fractions, you will see why we need $z^{-n}$ instead of $z^{n}$

Comment: @rsadhvika That shows nothing. The partial fraction decomposition doesn't force any choice of Laurent series expansion. Just like you can expand on $|R|>3$, you can also expand in $2<|R|<3$ and in $|R|<2$.

Comment: @minghan that doesn't show anything yet, that's just a start. If the OP responds, I'd love to guide him/her

Comment: @rsadhvika There is no theoretical reason. So, nothing that you intend to deduce from there will be an explanation.

Comment: @minghan there is a very good reason to expand as  $z^{-n}$ related to signals and systems, give it a try first

Comment: @rsadhvika Please. You give it try.

Comment: I would be surprised if it isn''t a convention chosen to align with exp(-j2*pi*ft) in the forward Fourier transform (where the opposite sign works equally well).

Comment: I'll post it as an answer @minghan sorry if my previous comment sounded offensive, I didn't mean to..

Comment: @JohnPolcari That's all it is.

Comment: I also agree with the Fourier series remark. It's a convention, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Same convention leads to exp(-st) in forward LaPlace transform.

Answer (score 5):

The Wikipedia article [Z-Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform#Geophysical_definition) explains that

> In **geophysics**, the usual definition for the $Z$-transform is a power series in $z$ as opposed to $z^{−1}$.

and continues

> The two definitions are equivalent; however, the difference results in a number of changes. For example, the location of zeros and poles move from inside the unit circle using one definition, to outside the unit circle using the other definition

Thus it **is** a matter of convention or preference. Something analogous applies to the Laplace transform and Fourier transform, especially for Fourier transform with differing factors.

---

{EDIT: 2023] The English Wikipedia article has been edited and now the
quotes I used in 2018 are no longer present in the article, however the
book reference to E. R. Kanasewich, *Time Sequence Analysis in Geophysics*, 3rd edition, 1981, page 186 still exists as confirmed by
Google Books.

> The $z$ transform was reintroduced by Hurewicz (1947) using $z^{-1}$
> instead of $z$ as defined in 13.2-1. This sign convention is common in
> engineering texts and such authors as Jury (1964), Ford and Hearne
> (1966). Bath (1974), Kulhanek (1976) and Claerbout (1976), etc.
> The classical definition is used in publications by Robinson (1963),
> Robinson and Treitel (1965), Van Nostrand (1971) and in this book.
> The ambiguity in sign should not cause confusion as long as a
> consistent definition is used throughout.

I think that the reason for the convention is due to the focus on
[causal systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_system)

> In control theory, a **causual system** (also known as a physical
> or **nonanticipative system**) is a system where the output depends
> on past and current inputs but not future inputs -- i.e., the output
> $y(t_0)$ depends only on the input $x(t)$ for values of $t\le t_0.$

> The causality of systems also plays an important role in digital
> signal processing, where filters are constructed so that they are
> causal, sometimes by altering a non-causal formulation to remove the
> lack of causality so that it is realizable.

Notice the prototypical case of the signal $x[n]$ given by the unit
step function $u[n] = 1$ iff $n\ge0$. Its $Z$-transform is given as
$1/(1-z^{-1})$ with ROC (region of convergence) given as $|z|>1$.
This is an example of a causal system since $u[n] = 0$ if $n<0$.
Notice here that the rational function $1/(1-z^{-1})$ is expanded
as a power series in $z^{-1}$ as
$1/(1-z^{-1}) = 1 + z^{-1} + z^{-2} + \dots.$
The non-causual signal $x[n] = -u[-n-1]$ is given the $Z$-transform
$1/(1-z^{-1})$ with ROC (region of convergence) given as $|z|<1$.
In this case, the expansion is in powers of $z$ as follows:
$ 1/(1-z^{-1}) = z/(z-1) = -z - z^2 - z^3 - \dots. $

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to explain why $z$ transform is easy to use in control systems and not power series. Consider a system with block diagram

[image]

It has the *system functional*
$$\dfrac{Y}{X}=\mathcal{H(R)}=\dfrac{1}{1-\mathcal{R-R^2}}=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}h[n]\mathcal{R}^{\color{red}{n}}$$

You could try long division or partial fractions and get the *unit sample response* $h[n]$. They all work pretty good if all you want is just the *unit sample response*. The only drawback is you can't see the *poles* directly in above form. So we engineers, being lazy, replace $\mathcal{R}$ by $\dfrac{1}{z}$ so that the roots of the quadratic in $z$ in the denominator give the *poles*. After this replacement, we call it the  *system function*  :

$$H(z) = \dfrac{Y(z)}{X(z)}=\dfrac{z^2}{z^2-z-1}=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}h[n]z^{\color{red}{-n}}$$

Comment: @Somos with the system functional, you have to factor it as $(1-\alpha R)(1-\beta R)$ then $\alpha, \beta$ will be poles right ?

Comment: With the system function, the factoring is $(z-\alpha)(z-\beta)$ and the poles are easy to *see*. My professor says this is the only reason for doing $\mathcal{R} \to \dfrac{1}{z}$ for DT signals

Comment: $a,b$ are the roots, they are not the poles. If we do partial fractions and expand, they will not be the base of geometric series right ? Poles in that case will be $1/a$ and $1/b$

Comment: We do a similar thing for CT signals. We replace the integrator $\mathcal{A}\to \dfrac{1}{s}$ and use the laplace transform

Comment: @Somos I think we're in same page. You want to solve it in terms of R and take the reciprocal of the roots to get the poles. I want to replace R by 1/z and solve to get the poles directly.

Comment: @Somos If I understand correctly, are you saying for causal systems the pole is $1/a$ and for non causal it is $a$ ?